# Build and test on 2.2.1 iPod Touch with Xcode 3.2.2?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

I've just installed Xcode 3.2.2 with iPhone SDK 3.2 Beta 5 (Snow Leopard)

This version of Xcode didn't come with any iPhone SDKs older than 3.0. But I want to create an app that runs on all devices from iPhone OS 2.2.1 -> 3.1.3.

I managed to add older SDKs into Xcode by downloading iPhone 3.1.3 with Xcode 3.1.4 and installing each 2.x SDK from the 'Packages' folder in the .dmg. So now I can select 2.2.1 as 'iPhone OS Deployment Target' and the 'Base SDK' as 3.1.3, and the app will build (thus letting me use 3.1.3 APIs with conditional coding whilst still running on 2.2.1 devices).

But the problem is the app will not install and run on my 2.2.1 iPod Touch. Instead, Xcode tells me 'No provisioned iPhone OS device is connected'. If I bring up the Organizer, in the left column, the iPod Touch has an orange sphere next to it, instead of green, and clicking on this reveals:

'The version of iPhone OS on “iPod touch” is too old for use with this version of the iPhone SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below'

I'm not sure how to get this version of the SDK to support 2.2.1.

(It needs to be this download of Xcode/iPhone SDK because I also want it to be a universal binary so it runs on the iPad with a minimum of fuss).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While under NDA, I can't be more explicit than to tell you to read [this thread](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/37798?tstart=45) in the Apple Developer Forums, which includes an explanation of this problem.

Comment: Thanks, I think this points out what's happening. Doesn't give a full explanation, but it looks like Apple want to move everyone forwards to 3.x

Comment: Check this document: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/checklist/, especially the final paragraph. I am not sure if I can quite it here, as the document requires login.

Comment: Yes, as of now, Apple no longer supports submitting applications to the App Store that target OS 2.x.  Everything must be 3.0+ going forward.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Apple recently made the 3.x updates available free of charge. I don't think there are any users out there still on 2.x!

Comment: I didn't know they were free. When I plug in my iPod Touch to iTunes I'm still offered the paid upgrade.

My analytics for other apps show around 15% of users are still <= 2.2.1. Don't really want to block out that high a proportion!

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question, and would make more sense as a comment.

Comment: I would have preferred to make a comment, but somehow I cannot (there's no comment button appearing).